# RML dotted line for a cell

Tags: rml

I need to know if exists some style like #lineBelowThicknes="1"# that allows me to have a line below the text that I wrote, but with points, example:

```
<blockTable style="default">
    <tr>
        <td lineBelowThickness="1">
            <para>
                Some text here above the line of the cell
            </para>
        </td>
    </tr>
</blockTable>
```

but instead:

lineBelowThickness="1" that gives me ______________________

I want this kind of line: ..........................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done but not as a property of the cell, The line it needs to be draw. Here there are some useful information about RML https://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf and more precisely (as an example):

```
<lineMode width="2" dash="5,5,2,10"/>
<lines>5.5in 4.5in 6.5in 4.5in
    6.5in 4.5in 6in 4in
    6in 4in 6in 4.75in
</lines>
<drawCentredString x="6 in" y="3.75 in">
    width=2, dash=5,5,2,10
</drawCentredString>
```